# Spring Batch Writer Object Array Insert

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

```
@Bean
public JdbcBatchItemWriter<MyObject[]> jdbcBatchItemWriter(){
    JdbcBatchItemWriter<MyObject[]> itemWriter = new 
    JdbcBatchItemWriter<MyObject[]>();
    itemWriter.setSql("INSERT INTO ITEM (ID, DESCRIPTION) VALUES 
    (?, ?)");
    itemWriter.setDataSource(dataSource);
    itemWriter.setItemSqlParameterSourceProvider(new 
    BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<MyObject[]>());
    return itemWriter;
}
```

I have an array of object called `MyObject` and I want to insert this to database.

Each subscript of `MyObject` represents a column for a row read from a database.

For example, MyObject[0] would be column `ID` for this instance and `MyObject[1]` would be column `DESCRIPTION`.

I want to be able to pass in a subscript of an array object to insert the values in my database. Like this

```
itemWriter.setSql("INSERT INTO ITEM (ID, DESCRIPTION) VALUES (0, 1)");
```

How should I approch this?

Comment: i assume its an string array (String[]) as every single element in the array represents an column and array cant have different type of elements. In that case why dont you make an class for the table and each col an field of that class, either way you can do it,  Confirm if you have same undertanding.

Comment: read spring batch first. https://spring.io/guides/gs/batch-processing/

Comment: I won't know how many columns or the data types of each column beforehand so I can't map out the table as an object

Comment: Something is missing here, ITEM table has definite number of cols which means you know number of cols its expecting. Are you saying you have unlimited number of rows to persist, if so that is possible.

Answer (score 0):

check out this fantastic article https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-batch-tutorial-writing-information-to-a-database-with-jdbc/

Try using named parameter. And while filliong the parameters, give values like following:

```
final class MyObjectPreparedStatementSetter implements ItemPreparedStatementSetter<MyObject> {

    @Override
    public void setValues(Myobject myObject, 
                          PreparedStatement preparedStatement) throws SQLException {
        preparedStatement.setString(1, myObject[0]);
        preparedStatement.setString(2, myObject[1]);
        preparedStatement.setString(3, myObject[2]);
    }
}
```